# Change the value of a custom field every first of each month WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress

i got this issue. I have 3 custom fields added with ACF on a single page, each one got a number.
I need to make a function that every first of month (day 1) make this add customfield1+customfield2 and update the result on customfield3.
Is it posible?

I tried with this function to see if i get the value correctly (without date calculation), but doesnt work:

```
function change_value_field($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){

  $num2 = get_field( 'numero_2' );
  $num1 = get_field ('numero_1');
  $result= $num1+$num2;

  if( get_post_status($post_ID) == 'publish' ){
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'numero_2', $result);
  }
}

add_action( 'post_updated', 'change_value_field', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

When updating fields while in a function that is not running on the current page, you will need to pass in the post ID to the `get_field` function, so that it knows which page to get that field from.

You can use the `wp_schedule_event` function to run the function daily and then check if the day is the specific day of the month you want the function to run otherwise do nothing.

```
if (!wp_next_scheduled( 'change_value_field')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'change_value_field');
}
add_action( 'change_value_field', 'change_value_field_function' );

function change_value_field_function(){
    if (date('d') === '01') {
        $post_ID = 1111;

        $num2 = get_field('numero_2', $post_ID);
        $num1 = get_field ('numero_1', $post_ID);
        $result = $num1 + $num2;

        // if you know the field exists already on the post and we are just updating you can use the acf update_field function
        update_field('numero_2', $result, $post_ID);
        // otherwise update the post meta
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'numero_2', $result);
    }
}
```